# Purchase Original Backing Tracks without Lead Vocals

Tags: instrumental

How can a purchase the original backing tracks without the lead vocals for a song recorded by John Michael Montgomery released by Atlantic Records Nashville.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably have better luck searching for a karaoke version - one re-done by someone else to sound like the original.

Try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=John+Michael+Montgomery+karaoke&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

The only record label I'm aware of that has released original recording backing tracks in any quantity are Motown. [Discogs listing](https://www.discogs.com/label/1607983-Motown-Original-Artist-Karaoke)

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good chance that you literally can't. If you've searched all the relevant storefronts (and/or checked google) and no instrumentals are available (you have done this, right?), it's probably just not for sale. I guess you can try contacting the label or the artist, but if they didn't want the administrative overhead of handling two releases for general sale, they almost certainly don't want the administrative overhead of putting together a second release to sell to literally one person.

You can most likely find relevant instrumental covers on one of the many sites selling karaoke CDs and mp3s. These will be of varying quality.

Comment: Soundcloud is usually the place for official vocal-only or backing-track-only versions of a song - couldn't find any for [JMM](https://soundcloud.com/johnmichaelmontgomery/albums) there at this link.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, most popular songs are available in karaoke versions, which are rerecordings of the instrumental part of the song, sometimes with backing vocals. They can sometimes sound almost identical to the original.

Sometimes rappers or rap producers will put out instrumental versions of their tracks, for use by DJs, but that is rare with other styles (with the exception of reggae dancehall).

It is possible with modern technology to digitally erase vocals, with varying levels of quality, but that's both legally and ethnically suspect.

Comment: Yeah, I avoided mentioning modern vocal removal techniques - partly for the ethics & partly because the good stuff [RX etc] costs a grand ;))